# Methods to create C# dictionaries, with static keys/values, in fluent notation

Tags: c#, hash-map, extension-methods, fluent-interface

I created these little utility methods to build fluent C# dictionaries. The value declarations shall be quick to write and easy to comprehend when somebody views the code. Usage conditions are as follows:

- many keys point to the same values
- group keys pointing to one value. Declare value only once for better visual comprehension.
- only relatively few values (usually 10 to 20, rarely up to 100)
- main application purpose: replace switch-case blocks in legacy code

The keys/values can also be added otherwise, such as from all constants or Resource content, and can be of any type useful to be declared in code.

In addition, I created an extension convenience method: simply `.ToDictionary()`, instead of constructor lambdas `kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value`

Is this good, or are there any problems or better ideas? What about performance when used frequently, compared to switch-case?

Usage/test:

```
class Program
{
    public const string RoadVehicles = "RoadVehicles";
    public const string RailVehicles = "RailVehicles";
    public const string Watercraft = "Watercraft";
    public const string Aircraft = "Aircraft";

    public static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> GroupsForVehicles =
        FluentDictionaries.KeysToValue(
            RoadVehicles, "Car", "Truck", "Tractor", "Motorcycle")
        .KeysToValue(
            RailVehicles, "Locomotive", "Railcar", "Powercar", "Handcar")
        .KeysToValue(
            Watercraft, "Ship", "Sailboat", "Rowboat", "Submarine")
        .KeysToValue(
            Aircraft, "Jetplane", "Propellerplane", "Helicopter", "Glider", "Balloon")
        .ToDictionary();


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var key in GroupsForVehicles.Keys.OrderBy(key => key))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(key + ": " + GroupsForVehicles[key]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The fluent methods:

```
public static class FluentDictionaries
{
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> KeysToValue<TKey, TValue>(TValue value, params TKey[] keys)
    {
        return keys.Select(key =>
            new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> KeysToValue<TKey, TValue>(
        this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> previous, TValue value, params TKey[] keys)
    {
        return previous.Concat(keys.Select(key => 
            new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value)));
    }

    public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> ToDictionary<TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> keyValuePairs)
    {
        return keyValuePairs.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
    }
}
```

Test output of the program above:

```
Balloon: Aircraft

Car: RoadVehicles

Glider: Aircraft

Handcar: RailVehicles

Helicopter: Aircraft

Jetplane: Aircraft

Locomotive: RailVehicles

Motorcycle: RoadVehicles

Powercar: RailVehicles

Propellerplane: Aircraft

Railcar: RailVehicles

Rowboat: Watercraft

Sailboat: Watercraft

Ship: Watercraft

Submarine: Watercraft

Tractor: RoadVehicles

Truck: RoadVehicles
```

Comment: What is your class doing which the regular `Dictionary` cannot do?

Comment: It's basically convenience, and to make a static key-value mapping in code visually better and reduce possible mistakes due to repeating the wrong result value (using common Dictionary initializer). No additional functionality.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a good idea but I don't think it is, at least not with the current method names that I agree with [@denis](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/153880/59161) are very confusing.

The name `KeysToValue` should actually be `AddValueWithKeys` because this is the order of parameters and it better suggests that the first parameter is a value and not a key. `KeysToValue` sounds like a query that gets something or converts keys to values etc.

---

I also find the extension should extend the dictionary and not some arbitrary `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` because if it will throw a duplicate key exception, it will be hard to find where it happened and it's of more use if extending a dictionary. If it however extends the `IEnumerable` then the name should be `Concat`.

The *improved* version could look like this:

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> AddValueWithKeys<TKey, TValue>(
    this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, 
    TValue value, 
    params TKey[] keys)
{
    foreach (var key in keys) dictionary.Add(key, value);
    return dictionary;
}
```

and is much easier to use as it now requries only a single extension

```
public static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> GroupsForVehicles =
    new Dictionary<string, string>()
        .AddValueWithKeys(RoadVehicles, "Car", "Truck", "Tractor", "Motorcycle");
```

Comment: Adding key-value pairs to the dictionary may be a good solution, instead of `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<,>>.ToDictionary()`. I just wanted to get rid of the mandatory, additional generic type declaration. I did not find the Dictionary constructor taking an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<,>>` as argument, only `IDictionary<,>`. Also, LINQ `.ToDictionary(...)` only supports it when specifying the key/value lambdas (therefore my convenience method).

Comment: @ErikHart oh, my bad, I was pretty sure there was such overload. I'll remove this part from my answer. You're right, it takes a dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Dictionary<,>` instantiation doesn't looks fluent to me at all, instead it looks overly-coupled with all kinds of extension method calls and it's kinda counter intuitive as the first element in a `KeyValuePair<,>` is usually the key, but in your case it's the value/s.

It's also hard to tell if all of those `"Car", "Truck", "Tractor", "Motorcycle"` will be connected in a way to your key or wait.. those were the keys..

I would suggest to create a separate class, which cleans up that for you:

```
public class FluentDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<TKey, TValue> _dictionary;

    public ICollection<TKey> Keys => _dictionary.Keys;
    public ICollection<TValue> Values => _dictionary.Values;

    public int Count => _dictionary.Count;
    public bool IsReadOnly => false;

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get { return _dictionary[key]; }
        set { _dictionary[key] = value; }
    }

    public FluentDictionary()
    {
        _dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    }

    public FluentDictionary(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> source)
    {
        _dictionary = source;
    }

    public FluentDictionary(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> source)
    {
        _dictionary = source.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator() => _dictionary.GetEnumerator();

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value) => _dictionary.Add(key, value);

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item) => Add(item.Key, item.Value);

    public void Add(TKey[] keys, TValue value)
    {
        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            Add(key, value);
        }
    }

    public void Clear() => _dictionary.Clear();

    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        TValue value;
        return _dictionary.TryGetValue(item.Key, out value) &&
                EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default.Equals(value, item.Value);
    }

    void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> collection = new List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>(_dictionary);
        collection.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        return this.Contains(item) && Remove(item.Key);
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key) => _dictionary.ContainsKey(key);

    public bool Remove(TKey key) => _dictionary.Remove(key);

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value) => _dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
}
```

Some extra functionality you might want to have is a way of obtaining all of the keys that point to specific value:

```
public TKey[] FindKeysMatchingValue(TValue value) => _dictionary.Where(
        pair => EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default.Equals(pair.Value, value))
    .Select(pair => pair.Key)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Nicely done! ;)

Answer (score 2):

I like your idea, but instead of ending the sequence of KeysToValue() calls with a call to ToDictionary(), I would make an Add-extension to IDictionary like below. You then only need one extension, and it is more flexible:

```
  public static class FluentDictionaries
  {
    public static IDictionary<TKey, TValue> Add<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TValue value, params TKey[] keys)
    {
      Array.ForEach(keys, k => dict.Add(k, value));
      return dict;
    }

    public static IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue> AsReadOnly<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict)
    {
      return dict as IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>;
    }

  }
```

**Use case:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  string RoadVehicles = "RoadVehicles";
  string RailVehicles = "RailVehicles";
  string Watercraft = "Watercraft";
  string Aircraft = "Aircraft";

  IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> GroupsForVehicles = new Dictionary<string, string>()
      .Add(RoadVehicles, "Car", "Truck", "Tractor", "Motorcycle")
      .Add(RailVehicles, "Locomotive", "Railcar", "Powercar", "Handcar")
      .Add(Watercraft, "Ship", "Sailboat", "Rowboat", "Submarine")
      .Add(Aircraft, "Jetplane", "Propellerplane", "Helicopter", "Glider", "Balloon")
      .AsReadOnly();

  foreach (var key in GroupsForVehicles.Keys.OrderBy(key => key))
  {
    Console.WriteLine(key + ": " + GroupsForVehicles[key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but naming them just `Add(...)` would confuse users, because of the reversed key-value order. This is necessary, because the `params` keyword can be applied only to the last method parameter (also, using a single array for both key and values would not be good: 1. possibly different types, 2. even more confusion what is key or value). The `AsReadOnly()` extension will not help me much, because I mostly apply this to `static readonly` fields, where I have to declare the type anyway.

Comment: @ErikHart: I really don't understand your arguments. Feel free to call the method whatever you want :-). The AsReadOnly() was just ment to be a  "Nice-to-have" method which by the way works perfectly with static readonly fields.